How to click a button in the drop-down menu using selenium in my java app?
I need to read data from a website and build menu objects based on this data.
But before I can do this, I need to use the English version of the site and click on the language change button in the upper right corner. The problem is that the language change button is not always clicked and the following exception occurs:

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".lang-list .lang-list-item:nth-child(2)"}

Here is my code:

The method with which the problem occurs because the button is not always pressed:
private void changeLanguage(WebDriver driver) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    WebElement languageMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("menu-switcher")));
    languageMenu.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.cssSelector(".lang-list .lang-list-item:nth-child(2)"))));
    WebElement enLanguage = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".lang-list .lang-list-item:nth-child(2)"));
    enLanguage.click();
}


Next, you find methods for building menus, getting links to all categories, and building categories:
 private Menu crawlExpirenza(WebDriver driver, String url) {
    driver.get(url);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    WebElement info = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("info-wrapper")));
    WebElement placeName = info.findElement(By.className("title"));
    Menu.MenuBuilder menuBuilder = Menu.builder();
    menuBuilder.placeName(placeName.getText());

    Map<String, String> allCategoriesLinks = getAllCategories(driver, wait);
    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String link : allCategoriesLinks.keySet()) {
        Category category = buildExpirenzaCategory(link, driver, wait, allCategoriesLinks);
        categories.add(category);
    }
    menuBuilder.categories(categories);
    return menuBuilder.build();
}

private Map<String, String> getAllCategories(WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait) {
    Map<String, String> allCategories = new HashMap<>();
    changeLanguage(driver);
    List<WebElement> sideMenuCategories = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.className("category__link")));

    for (WebElement sideMenuCategory : sideMenuCategories) {
        String href = sideMenuCategory.getAttribute("href");
        String name = sideMenuCategory.getText();
        allCategories.put(href, name);
    }
    return allCategories;
}

private Category buildExpirenzaCategory(String link, WebDriver driver, WebDriverWait wait, Map<String, String> allCategories) {
    driver.navigate().to(link);
    changeLanguage(driver);
    Category.CategoryBuilder categoryBuilder = Category.builder();
    categoryBuilder.name(allCategories.get(link));
    List<Dish> dishes = buildExpirenzaDishes(wait);
    categoryBuilder.dishes(dishes);
    return categoryBuilder.build();
}



Please help me to fix the changeLanguage() method so that the button on the link is clicked correctly and also so that it works for each category (Cheesecakes and other desserts, Bakery, Coffee and other drinks, Lemonades, tonics and others, Sparkling based cocktails, Organic and non-alcohol wine, Beer, Gifts and something else - All these categories have different links)
I tried using other web drivers and the mobile version of the site, but the button is still clicked only half the time.

There's something very strange going on on that page. All of the usual WebDriverWait types are not working when the page first loads for some reason. I tried presence, visible, and clickable and all of them timed out. I even tried waiting for stale thinking that the page loads and then reloads (even though I didn't see the page flash) and that didn't work. The only thing I could find that worked was adding a Thread.sleep(). This generally is a bad practice but when you have a site that is misbehaving as this one is, I couldn't find a better option.
I also changed the locator for the "EN" menu item to make it more clear, etc.
The code below is working for me consistently.
private void changeLanguage(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("menu-switcher"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='lang-list']/li[text()='EN']"))).click();
}

NOTE: You may need to tune the wait time. 5000ms may be too long or too short depending on the average time to load the page.

Yes, something strange is really happening on this page. I am very, very grateful to you, your method really works. Thank you very much!

Application is weirdly behaving, it locates the EN element sometimes and sometimes it won't.
You can use a small trick, use a try/catch block, catch the exception and try to click EN again in the catch block. I tested the below code and it works.
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://expz.menu/468539b8-d84b-42fa-b57c-6706d62b9acc/menu?menuId=585");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        
WebElement languageMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//p[text()='UA']")));
languageMenu.click();
        
try {
    WebElement enLanguage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//li[text()='EN']"))));
    enLanguage.click();
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Could not click on enLanguage at the first attempt, try clicking again after catching exception");
    languageMenu.click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.xpath("//li[text()='EN']")))).click();
}

NOTE: Above trick may still fail if the selenium fails to locate element even inside the catch block. Having said that, I tested the code quite a number of times and it consistently managed to click the desired element either inside try block or inside catch block.

can u try this ?
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    WebElement body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "menu-switcher")))
    WebElement language_menu = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "menu-switcher")
    language_menu.click()
    print('clicked language menu')
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lang-list .lang-list-item:nth-child(2)")))
    WebElement en_language = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lang-list .lang-list-item:nth-child(2)")
    en_language.click()

i did this in python and its works :
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://expz.menu/468539b8-d84b-42fa-b57c-6706d62b9acc/menu?menuId=585'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
body = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "menu-switcher")))
language_menu = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "menu-switcher")
language_menu.click()
print('clicked language menu')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lang-list .lang-list-item:nth-child(2)")))
en_language = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".lang-list .lang-list-item:nth-child(2)")
en_language.click()


This question is about Java. Posting an answer in python is not useful.

first code is java already

No, it's not. It's still python.

Also, I tried this code in python and it does not work.
